# concourse : destroy pipelines with fly command

Tags: concourse, fly

I have a list of pipelines called for example : 
test-run-First
test-run-Me
test-run-djfhd
test-run-jhfkjdh
...

I would like to destroy these pipelines, how can I apply :
`fly -t test destroy-pipeline -p "all pipelines starting with test-run-*"` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a reasonable approach to doing something like this would be to chain multiple commands together using pipes. For example you could achieve this using the following commands:

```
fly -t test pipelines | awk '/^test-run-/ { print $1 }' | xargs -n1 fly -t test destroy-pipline -n -p
```